# unable to add custom field

Tags: magento-1.9, sales

I would like to add two custom field for order process.

My config file:

```
    <resources>
        <sales_custom_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>Ucs_CatalogOrder</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </sales_custom_attribute>
    </resources>
```

Below is MySQl:

Location: app\code\local\Ucs\CatalogOrder\sql\sales_custom_attribute\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('quote_item', 'card_wallet_amount', array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Card handling Charges',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'visible_on_front' => 0
    ));
$this->addAttribute('order_item', 'card_wallet_amount', array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Card handling Charges',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'visible_on_front' => 0
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

After clearing cache I reload my page. When I check `core_resource` I can see the module sql record. But the fields haven't been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In older Magento quote and order are using EAV attributes but from Magento version 1.6 orders does not have attributes anymore.**

So instead of attribute you will need to create fields in `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` tables.

For that you will need to use alter table script in your sql setup file.

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_item')}` ADD `card_wallet_amount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order_item')}` ADD `card_wallet_amount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;");
```

And you will need to save your value in quote. In your module `config.xml` file you will need to convert your quote field to order. You can do like

```
<global>
  <fieldsets>
       <sales_convert_quote_item>
           <card_wallet_amount>
               <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
           </card_wallet_amount>
       </sales_convert_quote_item>
   </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am clear till the `$installer->run("ALTER TABLE ...` part. Whats the second part? Should it be required?

Comment: yes, it is require. I think you are talking about xml part. once you save your value to sales_flat_quote_item table and place your order. system will automatically copy this field value from sales_flat_quote_item to sales_flat_order_item table.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try it once and accept. +1 now. Thank you so much

Comment: But when I get order details using `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);` these custom values are not getting displayed?

Comment: you will need to get order items from this order object. you can get it my $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); also make sure in your order item table your custom field value saved correctly after placing an order.

Comment: Yes, the value from `sales_flat_order_item` has not been saved to  `sales_flat_order`, I am not sure how to save from `sales_flat_order_item` to `sales_flat_order`